# Eclipse AST Java Model: Where in ICompilationUnit stored whether it is class, interface or enum?

Tags: java, types, eclipse-plugin

[image]

How do I find out whether a compilation unit is an interface, class or enum? According to the graphic above it does not seem to contain fields storing that AST-information. And I can't find anything in the [DOCUMENTATION](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FICompilationUnit.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ICompilationUnit.findPrimaryType()` gives you the `IType` for the main class in the compilation unit (you can have more than one class in a compilation unit).

The methods `IType.isClass()`, `IType.isEnum()`, `IType.isInterface()` tell you about the type.